# How do I separate dynamic and static content appearing at the same URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, express, architecture

I am deploying a Web app consisting of both a static (marketing) site and dynamic app.

My goals are:

1. Separate dynamic and static content. Updating the static site should not take a code redeploy; updating the app shouldn't touch the static site.
2. Making it appear that it all lives at the same URL e.g. www.mysite.com

Think how Twitter works: http://twitter.com/privacy goes to a static page controlled by legal/marketing, while http://twitter.com/ goes to your feed.

I see a few options, could use some help:

1. **Appliance**: route based on URL like NetScaler / F5. Way too expensive, and doesn't play well in cloud deployments (Heroku/Jitsu/AWS/etc)
2. **Proxy**: static site deployed to a different URL (e.g. web.mysite.com), and dynamic site knows special paths and retrieves and caches the data. It works, but is complex and messy.
3. **CORS**: All static served from static site www.mysite.com, but loads application templates, JS, CSS, etc. from alternate api.mydata.com, and dynamic data via REST using CORS.

3 sounds nice, but worried about CORS browser support and still get some pollution across static and dynamic sites.

FWIW, implementing dynamic in nodejs, but could just as easily apply to RoR or even JavaEE.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind putting your static content in a specific subdirectory (like twitter's /privacy), then I think all you need to do is add that directory to your .gitignore (or other VCS ignore file), and deploy your app without that subdirectory. You'll need some other process to upload changes to the static content.

As for serving it, you should have a front end webserver (apache or ningx probably) or other proxy server serving all your static content anyway, including images and js/css from the dynamic part of your app. If your static site is .html etc anyway, then it should get served the same way, without touching your running application at all. You could also be more explicit in the web or proxy server configuration that it should serve everything in that subdirectory without forwarding the request to your application.

Comment: I agree in principle. The difficulty is in getting it uploaded when I don't control the server, i.e. when using a PaaS or similar. If I used my own infrastructure (i.e. were big enough), then I would have static servers and app servers and an F5 or NetScaler or whatever router in front.